# Разница между bean scope Singleton и Global-session?

Tags: java, spring

Пытаюсь понять разницу между областями бинов Singleton и Global-session.

Если мы делаем Singleton то контекст возвращает один и тот же бин.

```
final ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context =
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-context.xml");
```

При вызове `context.getBean(SomeClass.class)` будет возвращаться один и тот же объект если `scope=singleton` или ничего, но если мы укажем `scope=globalSession`, то результат будет тот-же.

Но есть же неявная разница...

А в чем? Как ее увидеть? И для чего это может помочь? Спасибо.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Из документации [Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes) :

> **singleton** (Default) Scopes a single bean definition to a single object instance per Spring IoC container.
> **session** Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of an HTTP Session. Only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext.
> **globalSession** Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of a global HTTP Session. Typically only valid when used in a Portlet context. Only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext.

**singleton**-бин имеет один экземпляр в пределах всего IoC-контейнера
**session**-бин имеет один экземпляр в пределах HTTP-сессии и умирает вместе с ней:

> When the HTTP Session is eventually discarded, the bean that is scoped to that particular HTTP Session is also discarded.

**globalSession**-бин почти аналогичен **session** - он используется в портлетных веб приложениях. Когда вы используется **globalSession**-бин в "стандартном" сервлетном приложении эти бины имеют *session*-scope:

> If you write a standard Servlet-based web application and you define one or more beans as having globalSession scope, the standard HTTP Session scope is used, and no error is raised
>
> Но есть же неявная разница...
> А в чем? Как ее увидеть?

Чтобы увидеть, что **session**-бин имеет разные экземпляры в разных сессиях (в "стандартном" spring веб-приложении), вы, например, можете обратиться к одному и тому же методу контроллера, в котором есть этот бин, из 2 окон браузера (одно в обычном режиме, другое в инкогнито).
Пример из приложения под рукой:

```
r.p.f.r.service.BlankServiceImpl@6f7b9a10 (1ое окно - http-сессия 1)
r.p.f.r.service.BlankServiceImpl@18d5bfc0 (2ое окно - http-сессия 2)
```

При повторных запросах используются все те же экземпляры (т.к. http-сессии все еще живые).
Если *scope* бина **singleton**, то экземпляр всегда один и тот же:

```
r.p.f.r.service.BlankServiceImpl@1fec9d33 (1ое окно - http-сессия 1)
r.p.f.r.service.BlankServiceImpl@1fec9d33 (2ое окно - http-сессия 2)
```